# In this question im trying to solve a problem about for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, sum, nested-loops

In this question I'm looking for any row or column which its sum is more than 2,the first row or column which is found break through the loop and printing yes if there isn't any print no. The code works fine for printing the sum of each row and column but it can't define if the input matrix has any row or column with such quality.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n,m,i,j;
int sum_r,sum_c;
int sw = 0;
scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
int a [10][10];
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
}
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    sum_r = 0;
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        sum_r += a[i][j];
        if(sum_r >= 2)
        {
            sw = 1;
        }
    }
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum_c = 0;
    for(j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        sum_c += a[j][i];
        if (sum_c >= 2)
        {
            sw = 1;
        }
    }
}

if (sw = 1) printf("yes");
else printf("no");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if (sw = 1)` -> `if (sw == 1)`

Comment: Also, you can immediately `printf("yes"); return 0;` to exit wherever you have `sw = 1` as there is no need to continue checking any more. Then at the end of the function you can have an unconditional `printf("no");` as reaching there would mean the condition is not found. So no need for `sw` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters there is a typo in this if statement

```
if (sw = 1) printf("yes");
```

You have to use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`

```
if (sw == 1) printf("yes");
```

Or simpler

```
if (sw) printf("yes");
```

If I have understood correctly then what you need is something like the following

```
for(i=0; !sw && i<m; i++)
{
    sum_r = 0;
    for(j=0; !( sum_r > 2 ) && j<n; j++)
    {
        sum_r += a[i][j];
        if(sum_r > 2)
        {
            sw = 1;
        }
    }
}

for(i=0; !sw && i<n; i++)
{
    sum_c = 0;
    for(j=0; !( sum_c > 2 ) && j<m; j++)
    {
        sum_c += a[j][i];
        if (sum_c > 2)
        {
            sw = 1;
        }
    }
}
```